# Reset Button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

`index.html`

```
<div>
    <button class="btn-danger" onclick="reset()">reset</button>
</div>
```

`main.js`

```
function reset() {
    let btnClear = document.querySelector('button');
    let inputs = document.querySelector('input');

    btnClear.addEventListener'('click',() => {
        inputs.forEach'(input => input.value = '');
    })
}
```

But it shows the following error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: inputs.forEach is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

Comment: Note that you can add `type="reset"` to the button and the browser will clear all fields automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector` return the first object. You're looking for `document.querySelectorAll`. Try that, and it should work.

```js
let btnClear = document.querySelector('button');
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
btnClear.addEventListener('click',() => {
  inputs.forEach(input => input.value = '')});
```

```html
<div>
    <input value="Try"/>
    <input value="Resetting"/>
    <button class="btn-danger">Reset</button>
 </div>
```